# ARMA-GARCH model: evaluate which factors affect the return of an asset

Tags: data-transformation, arima, garch

I'm working with data that includes the returns on a financial asset and 10 other variables (for example Google-searches). My aim is to test which of these factors affect the return (not the volatility). ARMA+GARCH is the model I am supposed to use for this study.

My questions are as follows:

1. Will the model, which I run in R, test the impact of all the variables, or do I need to test them separately?
2. Also, is there anything I should take into account about my data? My returns are log returns, but I could use percent-returns instead.
3. Is it possible to test with different lags?

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate the extra variables and/or their lags in your conditional mean equation next to the ARMA terms.

In R you can do that by using the package "rugarch" and functions `ugarchspec` and `ugarchfit`.

- Specify the model with `ugarchspec` by including these variables via the argument `external.regressors` within the argument `mean.model`.
- Estimate the model with `ugarchfit`.

The reported coefficients from the conditional mean equation will tell you the effect sizes of these variables.

If you follow this, then the answers to your questions are:

1. Yes, you will get the assessment of all variables at once.
2. Log-returns should be fine, as they approximate percentage returns quite well as long as the percentage returns are not too far away from zero (say, up to 15%). The nice property of log-returns is that they are additive, unlike percentage returns.
3. Yes, simply include the lags that you are interested in.

Comment: This is actually ARMAX model. He has exogenous variables and more interested in those coefficients.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc, thanks, I did not realize immediately that I had phrased it in an ambiguous way. Now it should be better.